# Obtaining a pointer-to-member from addresses of an object and its member

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

I'm looking to reverse the `.*` operator.

When I have a pointer I can dereference it with `*` and then from dereferenced value go back to the pointer by `&` operator.

With pointer-to-member I can dereference it with `.*` operator (supplying the object instance)  but there is no operator to obtain the original pointer-to-member from object and its dereferenced field.

Consider the following data structure:

```
struct Point { double x, y, z; };
```

Now I need to get a pointer to member `double Point::*` from `(Point&, double&)` pair, where that `double &` is a field of the `Point&` object.

In other words I need a function `to_member_ptr` such that:

```
template<typename DataType, typename Member>
constexpr Member DataType::* obtain_member_ptr(const DataType &that, const Member &fieldInThat);

int main(int, char*[]) {
    Point pt;
    static_assert(obtain_member_ptr(pt, pt.x) == &Point::x, "error");
    static_assert(obtain_member_ptr(pt, pt.y) == &Point::y, "error");
    static_assert(obtain_member_ptr(pt, pt.z) == &Point::z, "error");
}
```

I could write it by hand for given datatype as below:

```
constexpr double Point::* obtain_member_ptr(const Point &that, const double &fieldInThat)     {
    if(&that.x == &fieldInThat) return &Point::x;
    if(&that.y == &fieldInThat) return &Point::y;
    if(&that.z == &fieldInThat) return &Point::z;
    return nullptr;
}
```

But it seems like a plain boilerplate and I feel that there should be a way to make compiler do that for me.

How can I portably obtain a pointer to object from object and its field?

Comment: For what do you need that? Chasing a [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: You can't have pointer to a non-static *class* member variable. `&Point::x` is simply not valid since it doesn't exist. You can get an *offset* to the member variable from a class ([see the `offsetof` macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof)), but to get an address of a non-static member variable you need an object, an instance of a class.

Comment: Looks similar to the [singleton pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton).

Comment: C++ doesn't have reflection, but with extra library to add reflection to your class (as with `BOOST_HANA_ADAPT_STRUCT`), you may write a generic `obtain_member_ptr`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Actual use case is complex and not relevant. I'm not interested if I can solve my original problem in other way. I did it anyway. I'm just sure if the approach I originally intended is implementable in terms of compiler support.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `&Point::x` is valid — not as a pointer to variable but as pointer-to-member — that can be used together with any `Point` object to yield the actual `x` datafield.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'd be interested in Boost-based solution. Would be you be to post an answer with a sample solution using Boost.Hana?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [visit_struct](https://github.com/cbeck88/visit_struct), you may first add reflection:

```
struct Point { double x, y, z; };

VISITABLE_STRUCT(Point, x, y, z);
```

Then visit your struct:

```
template <typename C, typename T>
struct MemberPtrGetter
{
    constexpr MemberPtrGetter(const C& c, const T& field) : c(c), field(field) {}

    // Correct type, check reference.
    constexpr void operator() (const char* name, T C::*member) const
    {
        if (&(c.*member) == &field)
        {
            res = member;
        }
    }

    // other field type -> ignore
    template <typename U> constexpr void operator() (const char* , U C::*member) const {}

    const C& c;
    const Member& field;
    Member C::* res = nullptr;
};


template<typename C, typename T>
constexpr T C::* obtain_member_ptr(const C& c, const T& field)
{
    MemberPtrGetter<C, T> visitor{c, field};
    visit_struct::apply_visitor<C>(visitor);
    return visitor.res;
}
```